# The Binary Exponential and Louiville's Theorem

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Here is the problem statement:

Consider the sequence $\{2^n\}$ where $n$ starts from $0$ and goes to infinity. Consider the sequence where we take the first digit (from the left) of each element in the first sequence (so the sequence looks like $\{1,2,4,8,1,3,6,\ldots\}$. I am asked to use Louville's Theorem to determine the limit of this ratio : $$\frac{\text{number of 1s up to $N$th number}}{N}.$$

My guess is that the limit is not $0$ (then I guess the problem would be trivial), but I am not sure how to start.

Comment: Note proper MathJax usage, as in my edit to this question.

Comment: According to [OEIS sequence A008952](https://oeis.org/A008952), this sequence of digits follows Benford's law.